# How to add code that fixes urls in httpd.conf

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, configuration, httpd.conf, lampp

So the 'problem' im having is that 192.168.2.69/TEST does work, but when i go to 192.168.2.69/test it doesnt work. also happens with other folders or files. now i had soem type of code that fixed urls and with casing and just wrong writen urls. such as 192.168.2.69/TETS would go to 192.168.2.69/TEST and same for files.
though after a reinstall of xampp/lamp it was removed and i wasnt smart enough to think about that code.

btw: im using xampp 8.2.0 on linux (also called lamp)
OS = Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop

i tried everything, from googling, to asking chatGPT. nothing has worked so far.

I know my code had something to do with the rewrite_module, but i dont know the code itself anymore.
and please, do not come up with .htaccess files. i dont like those. i'd rather have code in my /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

Any help is appreciated alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know my code had something to do with the rewrite_module

The rewrite_module (ie. mod_rewrite) cannot correct arbitrary errors in the URL as you suggest in your examples. mod_rewrite can only correct specific/known errors - but that does not seem to be the case here.

You are probably looking for the Apache module [`mod_speling`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) (one `l`). This can correct case and single character differences in the URL (via an external redirect) when the URL is mapped to the filesystem.

Once the module is installed, it's simply a matter of enabling the spelling module in order to correct both case and single character differences:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

(Can be set anywhere... server config or `.htaccess`)

But note that this does put an additional load on the server and can potentially mask internal errors with URL creation.